# That $(\sin x)(\arcsin x)\approx x^2$ for small $x$ is clear from the Maclaurin series. Is there an intuitive explanation?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I know it may sound trivial, but if you look at the graph of $(\sin x)(\arcsin x)$, it's very similar to that of $x^2$ upto a certain point. Now this is because, when multiplying the Maclaurin expansions of $\sin x$ and $\arcsin x$, after $x^2$, the coeffecient of $x^4$ is $0$ , and the next few terms are small, starting with $\frac{x^6}{18}$.

Is there some intuition, possibly related to circles or the nature of the sine function? Or is it just a mathematical coincidence?

Comment: it's just because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x+\epsilon$. This is true of $\sin$ for small $x$.

Then $f^{-1}(x)=x-\epsilon$.

$f(x)f^{-1}(x)=x^2-\epsilon^2$.